# Integrate Spell Corrector/Checker on my Android App

Tags: android

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to develop an APP for my android device.

But I can't finish because I don't know how I can check the words (input) that the users introduce on it.

There's any library or other way that I could use for checking all the words that users introduce??

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify your question a bit? It seems vague when you say user introducing "words" --where? Into your app specifically? Into a web-browser?

Regardless I think UserDictionary is what you are looking for:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/UserDictionary.html

And if you are interested in adding or deleting such words you might consider using this:
http://udm.adrianvintu.com/